# The proportion of points for ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a list of data with the address and the frequency of certain incidents happened in those addresses(samples as below:)

```
     Address                        Frequency 
1155 6th Ave, New York, NY 10036         5
241 5th Ave, New York, NY 10016          7
171 W 57th St, New York, NY 10019        5
398-342 W 34th St,New York, NY 10001     10
```

I want plot those address in the map and using the frequency to determine the size of those points, here is my code and the result I got:

**Code:**

```
library(readxl)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

input <- read_excel("Add.xlsx")
geocodes <- geocode(as.character(input$Address), source = 'dsk')
mydata <- data.frame(input, geocodes)


mymap<- get_map(location = "Midtown, New York, NY", zoom = 14,
                maptype = "roadmap",scale = 2)

ggmap(mymap) + 
    geom_point(data = mydata, 
               aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = Frequency), 
               color = "Red")
```

**Result**:

[image: map with points]

However I feel the points for my addresses with smallest frequency are so small, well I know R has adjusted automatically, but is there anyway I can adjust the proportion and make them bigger? so I can present them better.

Comment: This isn't an RStudio problem, so I've removed the tag. Please only use that tag for problems with RStudio.

Comment: See `?scale_size_continuous` - you can adjust the `range` argument to make the smallest size bigger.

Comment: I think `scale_size_area` is recommended for `geom_point`

Comment: thank you all, i just add: 
ggmap(mymap) +geom_point(data = mydata, aes(x = lon, y = lat,size=Frequency),color="Red")+scale_size_area()